# Why does oidcUserAuthority.getUserInfo() return null after upgrading to 5.6.9 and 5.7.5

Tags: spring-security-oauth2

I have upgraded from 5.6.2 due to the new vulnerabilities. I also upgraded the other dependencies. In version 5.6.2, oidcUserAuthority.getUserInfo() returns the correct values. But in the newer versions of the jar, it is always null. How do you handle it?

Already tried upgrading all other dependencies to the same version and also updated the spring-aop etc to 5.2.23

Answer (score 0):

It's due to https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/12144 - the fix is scheduled for the 5.6.10 release.